# Minimal bash grub after installing on external SSD with live USB

Tags: boot, partition, grub

I installed [Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/) (which is based on Ubuntu) with a live USB stick on my external drive. During installation I didn't click on the partitions related to the partitions of the drive on my laptop. And I have no Windows.

What happened is that now my laptop cannot boot anymore. 
It complains very quickly about boot order and shows only GRUB minimal bash. 
To my surprise I see when I bootup the external drive a GRUB menu
which allows me also to boot the laptop.

I tried after booting into my laptop to `update-grub` and `grub-install /dev/sdb`, but no success.

Boot-repair tool also didn't help.

Then I tried these commands with the live USB:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt 
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi 
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi
```

But then I get an error `/usr/lib/grub/x86-64-efi/modinfo.sh` doesn't exist. 
However, this file does exist.

I am desperate now. Can someone please help me?

Screenshot from gparted of the internal drive (sda): 
[image]

Screenshot from gparted of the external drive (sdb): 
[image] 
___________ 
* The above images are cropped;
click on them to see the full, original images.

Booted into laptop via the external drive:

```
rob@Z1401:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery


rob@Z1401:~$ lsblk -o +PARTUUID
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT PARTUUID
loop0    7:0    0    80M  1 loop /snap/iced
loop1    7:1    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core
loop2    7:2    0  32.1M  1 loop /snap/snap
loop3    7:3    0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-
loop4    7:4    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core
loop5    7:5    0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-
loop6    7:6    0  61.7M  1 loop /snap/core
loop7    7:7    0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnom
loop8    7:8    0  32.1M  1 loop /snap/snap
loop9    7:9    0 301.1M  1 loop /snap/tele
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi  06d8ebaa-9738-4dc2-83d0-e8749d2f1241
└─sda2   8:2    0 446.6G  0 part /          ddb55d34-58c4-4684-a5f0-d98e63833648
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   487M  0 part            36147f65-c662-499d-b7cd-0c34028d02e3
├─sdb2   8:18   0   3.8G  0 part            87304a62-7722-4652-8e18-4ffe9d60d650
├─sdb3   8:19   0  57.2G  0 part            23a5a8c9-b0a5-4dfb-b9e4-a78a6bec8d12
└─sdb4   8:20   0   870G  0 part            cd350b6c-086b-4ca1-803c-2b4b284a1d0a
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Booted into ___???___ gives these results:

```
rob@Rob-Z1401:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
rob@Rob-Z1401:~$ lsblk -o +PARTUUID
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT PARTUUID
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi  06d8ebaa-9738-4dc2-83d0-e8749d2f1241
└─sda2   8:2    0 446.6G  0 part            ddb55d34-58c4-4684-a5f0-d98e63833648
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   487M  0 part            36147f65-c662-499d-b7cd-0c34028d02e3
├─sdb2   8:18   0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]     87304a62-7722-4652-8e18-4ffe9d60d650
├─sdb3   8:19   0  57.2G  0 part /          23a5a8c9-b0a5-4dfb-b9e4-a78a6bec8d12
└─sdb4   8:20   0   870G  0 part /home      cd350b6c-086b-4ca1-803c-2b4b284a1d0a
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Do you have an ESP - efi system partition on external drive? If so you can reinstall grub. If not you must create one first. Do not know for sure if Bodhi uses Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer, but that is an issue with external drives. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #55 or( #23 & #26)
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.  Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive.

Comment: You have identified both the internal drive and the external drive as both SSD and hard drive. I doubt that it really matters; if you believe that it’s important; please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation a few hours ago (a bit late for you, I regret..). Once the SSD is removed and the computer is started, just entering "**exit**" in the grub is enough to access to windows (at least, that worked perfectly for me).

However, I still haven't fugured out how to skip the grup when the SSD is removed....